# Cancelled ext4 shrink and now I can't seem to format the drive? parted, fdisk etc won't run with the drive

Tags: disk, fdisk, parted

I was shrinking an ext4 partition, however it was taking too long so I thought I'd just start from scratch (making a new partition and wiping the data). However after I cancelled the resize (which was done with gparted), I'm not able to use previously usable commands on this drive:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdc
echo $?             
1
```

parted just terminates, gparted doesn't show the drive either.

lsblk shows a 0 size drive

```
lsblk | grep sdc
sdc           8:32   0     0B  0 disk
```

fdisk

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdc

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.37.4).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdc: No such file or directory
```

Have I maybe damaged the drive itself doing this operation? According to https://www.scosales.com/ta/kb/104521.html it might be a hardware issue.

> If this error appears on the same device, no matter what its
> position is, then most likely there is some problem with the device
> hardware. Find out if there are any other frequent errors on this
> device. If there are, then most likely, it is a failing device.

dmesg logs when plugging in the drive (it's via a NVME -> usb external interface):

```
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:48 2023] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:48 2023] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=9210, bcdDevice=20.01
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:48 2023] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:48 2023] usb 1-4: Product: Best USB Device
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:48 2023] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: ULT-Best
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:48 2023] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 012938001753
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:48 2023] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:48 2023] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-4:1.0
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:49 2023] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Realtek  RTL9210          1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:49 2023] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:49 2023] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:49 2023] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Invalid field in cdb
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:49 2023] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:49 2023] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 0-byte physical blocks
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:49 2023] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:49 2023] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 37 00 00 08
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:49 2023] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:49 2023] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:49 2023] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:49 2023] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Invalid field in cdb
[Sun Jul  9 12:14:49 2023] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: `fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdc: No such file or directory` - you're trying to access the disk which is not in your system. Unplug/plug it in back again. Your dmesg log is incomplete regardless. Could be that the disk is dying, not geting enough power or a bad USB cable. This has nothing to do with shrinking.

Comment: It shows up with lsblk though? I've tried replugging / using a different USB port which results in no difference. This all happened after I cancelled the shrinking process. Maybe it's the external NVME interface that is struggling to correctly process the drive state after this.

Comment: Disks don't just disappear from the system but you choose not to show the rest of your `dmesg`. Maybe there are clairvoyants here I don't know - I'm not one of them, I can't help. *Have I maybe damaged the drive itself doing this operation?* - 100% impossible unless the drive already started failing. Never in my life I've seen NVMe to USB adapters.

Comment: Yeah, there are USB to NVMe adapters, but not vice versa.

Comment: I unplugged the drive, ran `dmesg -T --follow`, plugged it back in, then copied everything that got output from that point. I ask about drive damage as gparted had a warning which I think just said something like "cancelling will likely result in data loss" and I thought perhaps it actually said something about being unsafe to the hardware itself hence my question. If there is no hardware damage that will be great.

Comment: *"cancelling will likely result in data loss"* is **not** the same as physical damage. Your drive fails to show up which indicates that it's physically malfunctioning. There's nothing you can write to the drive to make Linux stop seeing it as a disk.

Comment: It's actually possible to make the drive malfunction using low level SSD/AHCI/NVMe commands but **not** using standard IO. There are special utilities for that e.g. HDAT2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugged the drive directly into my motherboard's NVME slot and everything worked, so it seems it was likely the NVME adapter being the issue here.

Based on `lsusb` it's a `Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL9210 M.2 NVME Adapter`.

Similar issues with this device are also reported here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/4130